# Autorefresh div every 3 seconds, run on initial load?

Tags: javascript

I have made the following script. Which checks the div #vs for updates and also checks the height of the div and adds a class to it if it exceeds 85%. This works great, but it starts working 3 seconds after the initial load. How do I make this load at the initial load of the page, and every 3 seconds after that?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

  var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
         $.ajax({
             success: function(data) {
                 var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
                     $('div#vs').html(result);

                     if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight > window.innerHeight * 0.85 )
                         $('div#vs').addClass('vscroll');

                     if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight < window.innerHeight * 0.85 )
                         $('div#vs').removeClass('vscroll');
                 }
         });


     }, 3000); // Refresh every 3000 milliseconds / 3 seconds
     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the function separately, call it once, and then call `setInterval` with it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function myFn() {
    $.ajax({
      success: function(data) {
        var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('div#vs').html();
        $('div#vs').html(result);
        if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight > window.innerHeight * 0.85)
          $('div#vs').addClass('vscroll');

        if (document.getElementById('vs').clientHeight < window.innerHeight * 0.85)
          $('div#vs').removeClass('vscroll');
      }
    });
  }
  myFn();
  var auto_refresh = setInterval(myFn, 3000); // Refresh every 3000 milliseconds / 3 seconds
})
```

Comment: That works very very well! Didn't know it was as simple as this, thank you for the clear example! I have one thing I wonder, right now it will first load the div as it is, and then a millisecond later add the class .vscroll to the div, which makes the text scroll. Is it possible to delay the initial load of the div for the javascript to take effect. Now it is "blinking", first showing it static text and then immidiatly scrolling.

Comment: Maybe just move the `.html()` call to the bottom instead of the top?